# Unusual behaviour while printing strings in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to input two strings in the same line with just a single space between the two and then print the same. But I do not get the desired output.

Here's the code for your reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct m
{
    char name[50];
    char phone[8];
}arr;

int main() {
arr a[100000];
int i, n, f;
char s[100];
char na[50];
char ph[8];
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%s",a[i].name);
    scanf("%s",a[i].phone);
}
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   printf("%s=%s\n",a[i].name,a[i].phone);
}
return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
```

The output I get is:

```
sam=99912222tom
tom=11122222harry
harry=12299933
```

Comment: missing `'\0'` terminator

Comment: Do you see that `char phone[8]`? How will that hold your 8-digit number  **and** the NUL terminator?

Comment: If you have 8-digit phone numbers, then you need 9 characters to represent them as a string:  8 for the digits, and 1 for the terminating null character.  You are writing past the bounds of your `phone` arrays and you are corrupting memory as a result.  Ideally you should *check* the length of your input before blindly storing it into an array that may not be large enough to hold it.  What if there are errors in your input, such as an extra digit or two?  You need to catch that, and give a meaningful error message.  Otherwise you will see more of this sort of thing.

Comment: Even after you fix the issue of `a[i].phone` not being large enough, please don't use `scanf`.  [It's notoriously hard to use properly](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), and with the way you're using it, you won't be able to prevent buffer overflows (which is what currently happens).

Comment: @ jamesdlin How should I take the input to prevent buffer overflows?

Comment: @Umang Using you ugly code with the declaration char phone[10]; I can not  reproduce the shown output.

Comment: @Vlad `char phone[8]` has been edited. Rolled back.

Comment: @Umang do you see what happens when you correct a mistake in the code? Commenters say there is nothing wrong. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Umang I think that the title of the question should sound like "One more usual behaviour while printing strings in C":)

Comment: @Umang Read the link I provided about avoiding `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. That helped me.

Answer (score 2):

When you were declaring `char phone[8]`, the debugger tells (no null-terminator):

[image: Debugger shows clarified results of error.]

But after changing, it places a null terminator which solves your problem. There was just a lack of null-terminator in your program. After changing the line:

[image: Debugger after fixing the code.]

---

Your problem will get solved after editing:

```
typedef struct m
{
    char name[50];
    char phone[8];
} arr;
```

Into

```
typedef struct m
{
    char name[50];
    char phone[9]; // increased by 1.
} arr;
```

Then you'll get something like:

```
3 // --- INPUT
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam=99912222 // --- OUTPUT
tom=11122222
harry=12299933
```

Answer (score 0):

to be able to use a value without having to hardcode that value into the `scanf()` the value must be `stringified`

The following proposed code

1. cleanly compiles, except warns about not checking returnd value from calls to `scanf()`
2. demonstrates the desired technique.

Note: it is a very poor programming technique to include header files those contents are not used.

Note: for flexibility it is best to separate the definition of a struct from a `typedef` for that struct.

Note: the OPs code contained several 'magic' numbers. Those 'magic' numbers have been eliminated by using `#define` to give each of them a meaningful name.

Strongly suggest using the `variable length array` feature of C, then eliminate:

```
#define MAX_A 100000
```

and modify:

```
arr a[ MAX_A ];
```

to be:

```
arr a[ n ];
```

and move that statement to after the call to `scanf()` that inputs 'n'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME 49
#define MAX_PHONE 7

//#define MAX_A 100000

struct m
{
    char name[ MAX_NAME + 1 ];
    char phone[ MAX_PHONE + 1 ];
};
typedef struct m arr;

// #define MAX_S 100
// #define MAX_NA 50
// #define MAX_PH 8

// following used to 'stringify' a value
#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(X) STR2(X)


int main( void ) 
{
    //arr a[ MAX_A ];
    int i;
    int n;
    // int f;
    // char s[ MAX_S];
    // char na[ MAX_NA ];
    // char ph[ MAX_PH ];

    scanf("%d",&n);
    arr a[ n ];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%" STR(MAX_NAME)  "s", a[i].name);
        scanf("%" STR(MAX_PHONE) "s", a[i].phone);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       printf("%s=%s\n",a[i].name,a[i].phone);
    }
    return 0;
}
```